# 'Download App' button on Application Page... how do you do that?

Tags: facebook, download

I'm a a bit stuck...

I see on the Spotify app page (http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=174829003346) you can see a 'Download App' button at the top. How do I replicate this on my own app page? I can't find anything in the app settings area that lets me set a URL for example. I selected 'native/desktop' app type but this doesn't give me anything else. My app is neither an Android or iOS app either. I want a link to my own website to download the app.

Please help...

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is an older feature of Facebook Pages that they say is now deprecated. If you had the link/button before they removed the functionality, it will still appear on your Page. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to edit/change/delete it.

This is the closest related thread I can find:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/236073243178846/